# Outlook Calendar Sharing Categories

Tags: windows, mac, microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

When you share a calendar. Is it also possible to carry over the category colors of someone else's calendar or is that a local only?

This is also for Office365 using Mac OSX 2011 and Office 2013 for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I know with Outlook on windows this is possible. It requires the calendar be shared with full details, which should then pass the color information on to the person consuming the calendar.

I'm not as sure with Outlook on Mac as it uses a different interface to talk to the server than Outlook on Windows, but suspect this should work here as well.